# How to use Museo fonts?

Tags: css, fonts

I've tried to use Museo fonts in my sites. But i don't know how to use this in a site.

If it is any google fonts like 'Roboto', then i can use by below code:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

Now how to use museo fonts?

May i use just **'Museo Slap'** or need to use **'Museo Slap', sans-serif;**

Comment: Get it from online. thats not a problem. I want to know only may i use just 'Museo Slap' or need to use 'Museo Slap', sans-serif; this is my question

Comment: yes u can, if you have font kit in your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit `sans-serif` if you wish, however I would recommend keeping it as it provides fallback support if 'Museo Slap' is not available.

For what it's worth, I think Museo Slap is actually known as **Museo Slab**.

Answer (score 2):

Either this process can be used to use text in a php file without having to put it in the css

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Custom Font";
    src: url(http://www.example.org/mycustomfont.ttf) format("truetype");
}
p.customfont { 
    font-family: "My Custom Font", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
</style>
<p class="customfont">Hello world!</p>
```

This is valid only for TFF or WOFF formats of font. replace src with the url of the font on your server. replace "My custom font" and "customfont" with the name of the font you want.

Or you can alternatively add the font to style.css with the code:

```
.font-face {
        font-family: "My Custom Font";
        src: url(http://www.example.org/mycustomfont.ttf) format("truetype");
    }
```